# how can i remove actionbar but keep drawer layout

Tags: android, drawer

as you can see i want to remove actionbar where pelaser word is but keep drawer so drawer will be available when finger moves from right to left.is there any way to do this?

[image]

what i did till now was hiding menu using this code

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: did you tried with hiding Actionbar? actionbar.hide(); ???

Comment: yes actionbar.hide method returns error

Comment: With Which Class you Have Extended your own class? Activity or AppCompactActivity or ActionBarActivity?

Comment: @AmanTonk  i used ActionBarActivity class

Comment: Then hide your ActionBar with getsupportableactionbar.hide();